# Jinja is not rendering HTML elements (even when using | safe)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask + sqlalchemy + jinja, retrieving data from a PostgreSQL database.

I have data stored in a PostgreSQL database that contains encoded HTML data, such as:

```
f = 1 / (2&pi;&radic;R(C&lt;sub&gt;1&lt;/sub&gt; + C&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;))
```

This is stored in a table `Questions` under columns | `q1` | `q2` | `q3` |

I want to retrieve all of these rows from the database and display them to the user.

My problem is that even after using `| safe` to properly display the HTML, I can not get jinja to actually *render* the HTML elements, as opposed to showing them as a string.

e.g. instead of displaying C<sub>2</sub>, it will show:

```
C<sub>2</sub>
```

**My Code**

On the backend:

```python
from app.models import Questions

@bp.route("/")
def index():
    all_entries = Questions.query.all()
    return render_template('app/index.html', all_entries=all_entries)
```

And on the front end using jinja2:

```html
{% for entry in all_entries %}
  {{ entry.q1 }}
  {{ entry.q2 }}
  {{ entry.q3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

So let’s say the first row has a `q1` of:

```
f = 1 / (2&pi;&radic;R(C&lt;sub&gt;1&lt;/sub&gt; + C&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;))
```

With the code above, I will get the output on the front end of exactly what is present in the database (as above), with no HTML encoding.

When I instead use:

```html
{% for entry in all_entries %}
  {{ entry.q1 | safe }}
  {{ entry.q2 | safe }}
  {{ entry.q3 | safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get `f = 1 / (2π√R(C<sub>1</sub> + C<sub>2</sub>))` as an output.

So `| safe` is correctly rendering the HTML entities (i.e. not escaping them).

**The problem is that it's not rendering HTML elements within the variables.**

So HTML elements like `C<sub>2</sub>` or `<a href="google.com">Google </a>` are rendering as a string, as opposed to rendering in their markedup form (e.g. C<sub>2</sub> and Google).

I've also tried:

- `{% auto escape false %}`. This does the same thing as `| safe`, but doesn't help render the HTML elements
- Iterating through the rows on the backend, passing it through `markupsafe`, and storing it in a dictionary. Again this stops Jinja from escaping the HTML, but it doesn't render HTML elements like `<sub>`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Using safe just disables escaping, it does not convert HTML entities to their non-entity equivalent. Your string needs to contain literal `<` and `>` characters instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`, the safe tag would then not escape those chars and render valid HTML tags

Comment: `html.unescape` would do the job https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape

Comment: Iain, you're an absolute superstar. It worked. I iterated through the rows on the backend using `html.unescape`, and stored the results in a dictionary. Then on the front end in jinja I used the `| safe` to disable escaping. And walaah—it worked. Thank you so much Iain :)